# Interactive Data UI for Non-Programmers

Tags: c#, database, vb.net, visual-studio

I've created a simple tool using a datagrid and adding functionality for cutting, pasting, deleting, adding rows, etc. The select users can create new, save, edit, delete from the database. Is there a better way to do this with some of the new technology from visual studio?

Answer (score 0):

There is a Microsoft application called [LightSwitch](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/lightswitch) which allows you to quickly generate relatively attractive forms that handle the default CRUD stuff you're looking for.

Right now it is still in beta though.

Comment: This happens to be just a small part of a Standard Windows Application that lets the user work with data. Is it possible to accomplish to just a part an application?

Comment: LightSwitch will generate a WPF application (XAML). I don't know exactly how easy it integrates with other .NET applications.